# How to apply integrity constraint on foreign key table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just started using SQL Server and have a question about integrity constraints with UPDATE and DELETE operations. To make it easier to explain, consider this simple example below, where the Contract_Header gives an overall information on the highest level about a contract, Contract_LineItem, which gives the annual information about the contract (each year = 1 entry), and Contract_LI_Status, a status of the LineItem, like 'In contract', 'Not paid', etc.

[image]

My problem is that I could update ContractID within Contract_LineItems to a whole different ContractID from Contract_Header, which would mean that the Contract_LineItem will refer to a whole different Contract than it is supposed to. The Contract_LineItem is supposed to be created automatically and not updated to any other ContractID afterwards. Though it should be delete-able.

Is it possible - probably it is - in SQL Server 2010 to restrict a certain value within a FK to be changed?

Comment: This rather sounds like a job for whatever frontend you are going to use to access the database. Values don't update themselves magically, so if you don't write any code to execute an update on this attribute it won't be touched.

Comment: Yes that is true. Creating these triggers for every possible table in the database would be unnecessary work. Perhaps this was more a 'wondering' question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to create a trigger that raises an error and rolls back the transaction if the foreign key column is updated. Something along the lines of:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterContractIdUpdate ON dbo.Contract_LineItem
FOR UPDATE AS
IF UPDATE(ContractID)
BEGIN 
    RAISERROR ('ContractID cannot be updated', 16, 1);
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot for the example! Tried and works :)